# Why, in Scala, does my Iterator[Match] give a length but have no data?

Tags: scala

I am trying to match on the braced text below using regex.findAllMatchIn and Iterator[Match]. This code below shows that the matchesOne has a length of non-zero in some cases, but then says it's an empty iterator.  I feel like I'm missing something basic here.  Any thoughts?

```
  import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match
  import scala.xml._

  val xmldata = <document>
    <content>
      <headers>
      </headers>
      <body>
        Foo [1], then another foo[2]; then lots of other things here
        And add a few other lines[2][3] of test data[3][5] (Foo 1234)
      </body>
    </content>
   </document>

  val bodyIterator : Iterator[String]= ((xmldata \ "content" \ "body").text).linesWithSeparators

  while (bodyIterator.hasNext) {
    val line = bodyIterator.next()

    println(s"*****   Line is: $line")

    val citationOne = """(\[[0-9]+\])(,\[[0-9]+\])*""".r
    val citationTwo = """(\([A-Z, -.]+[0-9]{4}\))""".r
    /* search the line for citations */

    val matchesOne: Iterator[Match] = citationOne.findAllMatchIn(line)
    val matchesTwo: Iterator[Match] = citationTwo.findAllMatchIn(line)

    println("matchesOne found: " + matchesOne.length)
    println("matchesTwo found: " + matchesTwo.length)
    for (m <- matchesOne) {println(s"match is $m")}

    println("matchesOne Matches: ")
    matchesOne.foreach(x => println("1: " + x.matched))
    //while (matchesOne.hasNext) {
    // println("matchesOne: " + matchesOne.next())
    // }

    while (matchesTwo.hasNext) {
      println("matchesTwo: " + matchesTwo.next().matched)
    }

    println("\n\n")
  }
```

Output:

```
  import scala.util.matching.Regex.Match
  import scala.xml._

  xmldata: scala.xml.Elem = <document>
    <content>
      <headers>
      </headers>
      <body>
        Foo [1], then another foo[2]; then lots of other things here
        And add a few other lines[2][3] of test data[3][5] (Foo 1234)
      </body>
      </content>
     </document>

  bodyIterator: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

  *****   Line is: 

  matchesOne found: 0
  matchesTwo found: 0
  matchesOne Matches: 



  *****   Line is:       Foo [1], then another foo[2]; then lots of other things here

  matchesOne found: 2
  matchesTwo found: 0
  matchesOne Matches: 



  *****   Line is:       And add a few other lines[2][3] of test data[3][5] (Foo 1234)

  matchesOne found: 4
  matchesTwo found: 0
  matchesOne Matches: 



  *****   Line is:     
  matchesOne found: 0
  matchesTwo found: 0
```

Comment: All set now. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [`Iterator.length`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@length:Int) exhausts the [`Iterator`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator), as stated in the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@length:Int):

> *Note* - Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on.

Comment: Ah, missed that part in the documentation. And that totally makes sense, given an iterator.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Calculating the length of an iterator consumes it (because it has to process all the elements to see how long it is). So after the length is known, the iterator is now empty
!

Answer (score 1):

When you get the length of your iterator, you already are at the end of it, so you cannot get any data afterwards. In your case, a solution would be to convert it to something like List.

```
   val matchesOne: List[Match] = citationOne.findAllMatchIn(line).toList
   val matchesTwo: List[Match] = citationTwo.findAllMatchIn(line).toList
```

Then you will get the expected output, e.g.:

```
scala> val line = "Foo [1], then another foo[2]; then lots of other things here"
line: String = Foo [1], then another foo[2]; then lots of other things here

scala> val result = citationOne.findAllMatchIn(line).toList
result: List[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = List([1], [2])

scala> val matchesOne = citationOne.findAllMatchIn(line).toList
matchesOne: List[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = List([1], [2])

scala> println("matchesOne found: " + matchesOne.length)
matchesOne found: 2

scala> for (m <- matchesOne) {println(s"match is $m")}
match is [1]
match is [2]
```